# ImageIcon color issue when I fetch from assets in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm starting to learn flutter and at the moment, I'm trying to show an image from assets, but it's color going to change and I don't know why.

```
 IconButton(
        icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icons/library.png")),
        onPressed: (){

        },
      ),
```

This is original red icon

[image]

And after fetching from assets it's looks like

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the differences between the first and second images? They look identical with the second one shifted left.

Comment: Sorry I have added second correct image right now please see know thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? Share your file structure and `pubspec.yaml` as well.

Comment: There have no any error in log, and it's just going to decolorize and when I used only one color icon then it's looks fine ha

Comment: Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this before, the image must be of a **PNG** type, and it should be background is empty.

Or using it in another way, like this:

```
InkResponse(
        icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/library.png",width: 30,height: 30,),
         onTap: (){

         },
      ),
```

Comment: it's working fine
 InkResponse(
            child:Image.asset("assets/icons/library.png"),
            onTap: (){

            },
          ),
Thanks @farouk osama